# How to get multiple instagram pictures from a # using the API

Tags: instagram-api

I want to get the 50 most recent pictures from a given hashtag and display them on an MVC website. I've looked on the official instagram API and can't find anything regarding getting multiple images from a hashtag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else encounters the same problem, this is what I did:

Adding "?__a=1" to the end of a link to an instagram hashtag gave me some json that I used [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize into a C# object. In it was the link to each image and I then used that as the source to my images on my website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .net framework here is some python code which can be implemented into your project:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json


class Insta_Image_Links_Scraper:

    def getlinks(self, hashtag, url):

        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=self.ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        script = soup.find('script', text=lambda t: \
                           t.startswith('window._sharedData'))
        page_json = script.text.split(' = ', 1)[1].rstrip(';')
        data = json.loads(page_json)
        print ('Scraping links with #' + hashtag+"...........")
        for post in data['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['graphql'
                ]['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']:
            image_src = post['node']['thumbnail_resources'][1]['src']
            hs = open(hashtag + '.txt', 'a')
            hs.write(image_src + '\n')
            hs.close()

    def main(self):
        self.ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        self.ctx.check_hostname = False
        self.ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

        with open('hashtag_list.txt') as f:
            self.content = f.readlines()
        self.content = [x.strip() for x in self.content]
        for hashtag in self.content:
            self.getlinks(hashtag,
                          'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'
                          + hashtag + '/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Insta_Image_Links_Scraper()
    obj.main()
```